# How do use recursive type definitions in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have seen this example in the typescript 3.7 notes

```
type Json =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | null
  | { [property: string]: Json }
  | Json[];
```

But I'm not sure I get how to use it.

For example lets say I have function `MyJSON.parse` that is typed as returning a `Json`

```
declare var MyJSON: {
  parse: (s: string) => Json;
};
```

vs `JSON.parse` which is typed as returning `any`

This works,

```
const j1 = JSON.parse('{foo: 123}');
console.log(j1.foo);
```

This fails

```
const j2 = MyJSON.parse('{foo: 123}');
console.log(j2.foo);
```

The first error `'j2' is possibly 'null'.(18047)`. So let's tell it it's not null

```
const j2 = MyJSON.parse('{foo: 123}')!;
console.log(j2.foo);
```

The next error is `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | { [property: string]: Json; } | Json[]'. Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'string'.(2339)`

Now to some degree, I get what it's saying. `foo` only possibly exists on one of those types.

So my question is: Is it possible to type this such that in typescript would not complain about the example `console.log(j2.foo)` above but would still enforce the types. For example

```
j1.foo = new Image();   // should fail because `Image` is not valid for `Json`
```

In my particular case my type is more restricted. Something like

```
type DataCollection =
  Float32Array
  | { [property: string]: DataCollection }
  | DataCollection[];
```

But I run into the same issue. I have a function that returns an DataCollection. I know what properties will exist for a given input but I can't access them without lots of typescript warnings. Casting everywhere will make the code unreadable so I'm trying to find some middle ground rather than revert to `any`

Ideally I could opt into maximally accepting type so given

```
const d = getSomeDataCollection();
d.set(...);     // OK because d could be a Float32Array
d[0].set(...);  // OK because d could be an array of Float32Array
d.foo.set(...); // OK because d could be {[property:string]: DataCollection}
d.min(...);     // Error because there's no completion of d that
                // contains a `min` function
d == "hello";   // Error because there's no version of `d` that is
                // comparable to string
```

maximally accepting is like the difference between

```
interface PersonI {
  name: string;
  country: string;
}
```

and

```
type PersonR = Record<string, string>
```

`PersonI` is minimally accepting.

```
const p = getPersonI();
console.log(p.nickname.length);  // Error, there is no nickname
```

vs `PersonR` which is maximally accepting

```
const p = getPersonR();
console.log(p.nickname.length);  // Ok even though `nickname` may not exist
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHZQLwCgpQD5TsAJwEskBzTHKJAVwFsAjCAi3ehBAGwgEMkWrqHDvwDeUANpgCCSAVAAuPIRKkAuovjIoAX36ak41QG506ACYQAxh24FoAN1tQAsiBgBlAPIA5RSIpgtnAQigAUcIr4xGQAlGgAfLCISCbaJqaWyPhQAFYAjGiwXt4AdIEEwaEA5CIAZuyKeQBMAMzaVTEmmUiIXCUcCKSh+SX1CJ0ZWcC5TYWuHj5lQRDVdQ1QzW0dAIRdWZwQ-YPDTaPsE+igkFAAItzA3ADCnFyWwERaGFgAYgP3LU0AIIEAjcECiCRSGRMBRKaJqRR3B7PIRWd5aXRYXBIp4vNEfAzGUwWay2BxOUgQYAo17opBhOKoRI4mn45DpbrZSyFSnUvFvAmhCacg5HIaWM7jIxAA)

Comment: I'm not really sure what outcome you are expecting here. Your JSON type is a very wide union, as is you `DataCollection` type. TypeScript is a compile-time construct, it can not magically infer whether the runtime result of calling `MyJson.parse()` will be a string, boolean, number, null, array, or some object that happens to have the property `foo`. If you yourself are not able to more narrowly define the type that is returned from a certain operation, TypeScript can also not do that for you.

Comment: `maybeFloat32Array.someUnknownPropHere` _should_ be a type error until you narrow that down.

Comment: I guess I was hoping for a way to be maximally inclusive instead of minimally. As it is I'd have to cast `j2` to a `{ [property: string]: DataCollection}` to see `foo` (minimally inclusive) where as I'd prefer the opposite, given I typed `.foo` assume `.foo` must be a `DataCollection`. Note: This is arguably no different than `r = Record<string, Float32Array>; r.foo`. Typescript doesn't know `foo` exists but it assumes I know what I was doing and therefore assumes it's a Float32Array where as by definition it might be undefined since typescript doesn't know what properties exist at runtime

Comment: Typescript "assuming you know what you are doing" is not really the Typescript philosophy. Instead, the philosophy assumes we're all idiots and prone to making all manner of mistakes. This point of view has proven to be correct about me in my experience. So doing the hard way is the point.

Comment: You probably are looking for json parser on type level. See [this](https://twitter.com/buildsghost/status/1301976526603206657)

Comment: @AlexWayne, my `Record` example contradicts your opinion. If typescript assumed we were all idiots then `Record` wouldn't exist and you'd be required to type every key

Comment: There's a lot of typescript features with varying levels of type safety. `any` exists, for instance, which isn't recommend that anyone actually use in the vast majority of circumstances. `Record<string, SomeType | undefined>` would be a safer way to write a `Record`. But that `Json` doesn't need that since `Json` can be `null`, which gets you pretty darn close.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` only *"works"* because it returns `any`, which tells you nothing about any types whatsoever. Returning the `Json` type at least constrains the possibilities and forces you to check the values before you use them as anything specific.

As with any union, in order to use a value as just one member of that union you have to check it:

```
const j2 = MyJSON.parse('{foo: 123}')!;
if (typeof j2 === 'object' && !Array.isArray(j2)) {
  console.log(j2.foo); // j2.foo is JSON
}
```

So in your recursive union type, you just have to check at each level and determine what's there:

```
type DataCollection =
  Float32Array
  | { [property: string]: DataCollection }
  | DataCollection[];


// mock a value type as a DataCollection
declare const collection: DataCollection

if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
  collection // plain array
} else if (collection instanceof Float32Array) {
  collection // Float32Array
} else {
  collection // { [property: string]: DataCollection }
  collection.foobar // DataCollection
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBhA9gGzRAxsAligOygF4AoKKAMTRQQGYAmAQQCcW4RyoAfKAbygBtMCxSQWoAFxQAzsBa4CAcwC60+IlQZseQlAC+XXhuTpMOfAUEqA3KXsB6B1AC2KLAGsocKADc4aACu0KCQ3jLesAim2haEpAAm2GhwLNBYhHJQGbG6BOrRWuZ59rgAZlAAFKzsIAB0uDI1HJU5xZYAlB38XG06llBOUGApit5sHKT6UBBoMtDlVX1xRIpycARYECgV1LTAjM0g3Xy9Zv16Q3v0zBOc07PzPRTLeYPOAsKi4lKy8oqqAqac4rAxnXKWOplFAoABGqXeUWBEPihiAA)